# Score computation in OpenCV bag-of-words classifier

Tags: c++, opencv

I don't know how the score is computed in the bag-of-words classifier of OpenCV, i.e. in this code: `bagofwords_classification.cpp`

Is it related to precision and recall or not?

Comment: You mean "how the score is _computed_", right?

Comment: yes. That's what I mean. :)

Comment: Ok. I've edited the text to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official doc. You may have a look at [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html)